# linux ffmpeg get rtmp stream and convert into a live webcam v4l2

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, flv, avconv, v4l2

So I simply try out to get the stream and convert it into a rawvideo and create a new webcam with v4l2.

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX/test" -vcodec rawvideo -y -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

It is working a long time and then I got this:

```
ffmpeg version 2.7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX/test':
  Metadata:
    fileSize        : 0
    audiochannels   : 2
    encoder         : obs-output module (libobs version 0.10.1-67-g94edb7f)
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 1774.608000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 2560 kb/s, 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s
[v4l2 @ 0x7f7326cb4480] Unable to open V4L2 device '/dev/video2'
Output #0, v4l2, to '/dev/video2':
  Metadata:
    fileSize        : 0
    audiochannels   : 2
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 rawvideo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
```

Comment: converting a media stream into hardware is a tough task :-)

Comment: when do you get the error? e.g. do you call ffmpeg to feed the loopback device and t works for (e.g.) 10 minutes and then stops? or does it fail to start at (seemingly random) times? or did it work well on one machine but now you are using a different one (or have upgraded) it stopped working altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create virtual video devices you need to install and enable [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback). The "No such file or directory" message means you didn't enable the device.

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=2
```

This will create the `/dev/video2` device.

**Update**: in response to umläute's comment make sure the v4l2loopback module is persistent, just in case your server reboots. Uptime can be very long.

Example for CentOS: [Persistent Module Loading](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-kernel-modules-persistant.html)

Comment: seems like the OP already has *v4l2loopback* running, else i cannot explain the "it is working a long time"...

Comment: I interpreted as "it takes long time and then fails". Time is relative :)

Comment: ah, you mean as in "it stalls for some time and then returns to the console with an error message"; rather than "it works for some time; and then fails"

Comment: yeah, updated the answer to account for kernel module persistence